# Host Shared connection to <host-ip> closed - Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-awx

I'm trying to add a new RHEL 8 host to the Ansible Tower. Host variables are as follows,

`ansible_host:

ansible_port: 22

ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python2.7`

Then tried to run a playbook on the above host through Ansible Tower. I got the below error.

```
{

"_ansible_no_log": false,

"failed_modules": {

"setup": {

"failed": true,

"rc": 1,

"msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",

"module_stderr": "Shared connection to <``host-ip> closed.\r\n",

"module_stdout": "\r\n"

}

},

"msg": "The following modules failed to execute: setup\n",

"changed": false,

"_ansible_verbose_override": true,

"ansible_facts": {}

}
```

TASK: Gathering Facts

MODULE: gather_facts

Yes, I've checked the Python versions and paths, and they are there. Is this a known issue? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the IP address in ansible_host:

ansible_host: 10.10.10.10